# How to generate uniform distributed random number in VS 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, random

I am trying to create a class that includes a uniform distributed random number. I use Visual Studio 2010 c++.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee462299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462299.aspx

Tried many combinations from these two links but I can't find the solution for my needs.
My current code is:

A) MyProblem.h

```
#include <random>

class MyProblem
{
public:
  int calculateMyProblem();

private:
  double _uniformRandNum;
  std::mt19937 _generator(1729);   // for 1729 I get ERROR: Expected a type specifier
  std::uniform_real_distribution<> _distribution(0,1); // for both 0 an 1 i get ERROR: Expected a type specifier
  void generateUniformDistrNum();
  void calculateMeanDistance(); 
};
```

For the two lines i get the errors

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
```

B) MyProblem.cpp

```
MyProblem::MyProblem()
{}

int MyProblem::calculateMyProblem()
{
  generateUniformDistrNum();
  // other stuff to be done with random number _uniformRandNum

}

void MyProblem::generateUniformDistrNum() 
{
    _uniformRandNum = (double) _distribution(_generator); // ERROR, see below
}
```

The generated errors are:

```
error C3867: 'MyProblem::_generator': function call missing argument list; use '&MyProblem::_generator' to create a pointer to member

error C2660: 'MyProblem::_distribution' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

I am trying for an entire day now I couldn't figure it out. How can I fix these?

Comment: In C++ a _constructor_ is used to initialize an object and its members.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize members (that are not static or const) in class body using (). You need to do it in constructor initialization list or in it's body (or outside the class definition in one source file as for static members:

header file:

```
class MyProblem
{
public:
  int calculateMyProblem();

private:
  double _uniformRandNum;
  std::mt19937 _generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<> _distribution;
  void generateUniformDistrNum();
  void calculateMeanDistance(); 
};
```

source file:

```
MyProblem::MyProblem() : _generator( 1729), _distribution( 0, 1) {}
//... the rest of function defs
```

In C++11 however you can use {} to initialize the members in class body:

```
class MyProblem {
    //...
    std::mt19937 _generator{1729};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> _distribution{0,1};
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're using C++11's non-static data member initializers to initialize data members within the class definition, you must use braces (or equal) to do the initialization. Your code will be correct if you change the two offending lines to

```
std::mt19937 _generator{1729};
std::uniform_real_distribution<> _distribution{0,1};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4a216a3a51feee0)

However, this will still not work on VS2010 (I think you need VS2013 for it to work). So your only option with that compiler is to perform the initialization in the constructor's initializer list.

```
MyProblem::MyProblem()
: _generator(1729)
, _distribution(0,1)
{}
```